# Customize django-storage s3 url?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, django-storage

I am using django-storages to let user upload the image file to my S3 and I have a cloudfront distribution works with the bucket in s3.

I am able to upload the file to s3 but I cannot change the url of the image file to use cloudfront distribution url.

The url is always set to the s3 bucket url.

Is there a way to customize the url?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'd want to override [URL method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.url)

Answer (score 2):

In your productions settings use:

`AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'cdn.mydomain.com'`

Source docs: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Answer (score 0):

An approach to solving this problem that I took, was to create a new templatetag called 'static_cdn'; and it would do some checking to say "Am I local, dev, production, etc" and would munge the domain appropriately depending on where it was. It makes no sense to generate CDN traffic if I am just screwing around locally (or, at least, I'm not there yet).

A different approach I considered was to override the default static tag entirely, and put the logic in there, but for now I wanted to maintain the granularity so that if, for some reason, I wanted to fetch directly from S3 and not CloudFront on production servers, I had that ability.

edit: Example code might look something like this:

```
# Import: Django
from django.template import Library
from django.templatetags.static import static

# Static CDN
# - We could probably go in and overwrite the default static template tag
#   and decide to use the CDN or not; for now, though, I want the option
#   (even remotely) to explicitly use the CDN or not.
def static_cdn(url):
    if not LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT:
        # StackOverflow: Do not do this! Import/Write/etc an urljoin (see Django code
        # for examples - you can probably import the version Django uses internally.
        return 'https://{0}{1}{2}'.format(AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, STATIC_URL, url)
    else:
        return static(url)

# Register
register = Library()
register.simple_tag(static_cdn)
```